# $\int_{\frac{\delta}{2}}^{\delta}\dfrac{F^{\prime}(x)}{F(\delta)}dx \leq C$

Tags: integration, functions, continuity, lp-spaces

> Let $f:[\frac{\delta}{2},\delta] \to \mathbb{R}^{+}$, continuous. Here, $\delta >0$ small. Define, $F(x) = \int_{\frac{\delta}{2}}^{x}f(s)ds$. Note that $F^{\prime}(x) = f(x)$. What conditions do I have to put on the function $f$ to show that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that
> $$
> \int_{\frac{\delta}{2}}^{\delta}\dfrac{F^{\prime}(x)}{F(\delta)}|g(x)|^{2}dx \leq C ?
> $$
> where $g \in L^{2}\big(0,1)$.

If $f$ is increasing, does it work? That's all, I'm not getting it.

Comment: Isn't $\int_{\frac{\delta}{2}}^{\delta}\dfrac{F'(x)}{F(\delta)}dx=\dfrac{1}{F(\delta)}\int_{\frac{\delta}{2}}^{\delta}f(x)dx=\dfrac{F(\delta)}{F(\delta)}=1$?

Comment: Yes. I had the wording wrong, there was a $g$ function missing. That's why it came out so easy. I'm sorry.